# Visual studio live share limited functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vscode-liveshare

I was looking for a solution to the problem on many internet forums, but I couldn't find it. The topic always ends with the sentence - that we will fix this problem with the next VS update. (Since 2017...). Even after updating VS nothing changes. When I try to share my project with Live share, **my guest cannot access the project files and can't open them**, he gets an error:

```
The Output Channel Recipient has limited functionality due to the lack of the dependency service: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OutputChannelStore (0.1).
C ++ Service has limited functionality due to the lack of a dependency service: Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.ManagedPackageService.
```

I use visual studio 2022 community. Since April, there have been a lot of entries about this problem, but somehow there is no solution, anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

With current version of VS(which was downloaded on 16.12.2022) live share works correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).